# Extracting information from file into website

Tags: html, spreadsheet

How would I extract information from a file (i.e. word document, spread sheet) and put it into a website? For instance, I am working on an announcement feed for my school website where when an administrator updates information on a document, that information will be automatically updated on to the website.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO;

Answer (score 0):

First of all - it's a fairly complicated programming task, in some environments it might be impossible.

If you are not the programmer who is going to implement it, I'd recommend to ask the responsible person about the way you need to follow.

Said that, if you are about to implement that I see 2 most adequate ways:

- Use Google Docs API

Google docs are basically the same as Excel & Word documents except they support collaborative editing & have a cool, easy to use API.

- Use a specialized tool or library

Considering you want to parse an Excel & you have back-end written in PHP, you might use [this package](https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx).